# remove msg from ActionMessage

Tags: java, struts

How do I remove a particular error message from ActionMessage. For example, below `msgKey` is `"ABC"` and `msg.getKey()` is `"ABC"`. Now when both are same I want to remove the key from the ActionMessage. How do i do it?

```
Iterator it = warningMessages.get(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE);       
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ActionMessage msg = (ActionMessage) it.next();
    if (msgKey.equalsIgnoreCase(msg.getKey())) {
                // remove msgKey from warningMessages
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can empty the warningMessages object and re-add those messages in which you are interested?

Comment: i have a big list and need to deleted only 1. So i think this would be a tedious task especially when size is more. but if no other option i wil have to consider this.

Comment: There is no `remove` method in the `ActionMessages` class. Since you - on average - will have to iterate over half the messages anyway, the overhead exists either way.

Comment: This is how i get the warning messgae ActionMessages warningMessages = getMessages(request);. So I went and initialized it like this ActionMessages warningMessages = new ActionMessages(); But still i see the warning message. So I see it is stored somewhr in request. How do i remove this warning mesage in request. any pointers?